# Show derived measure in aggregate bar chart

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, saql

I want to show a bar chart with list of opportunities and total days it took to close the opportunity. I tried the below query

```
q = load "DTC_Opportunity_SAMPLE";
q = foreach q generate 'Opportunity_Name' as 'Name', ('Close_Date_day_epoch' - 'Created_Date_day_epoch') as 'Time to close';
q = order q by 'Time to close' asc;
```

However, It is showing a table with opportunity name and total days it took to close the opportunity. 
I wanted to show it in bar chart. 
Can anyone please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click on the widget in your dashboard or the lens (however you created it). In the top right corner, you can switch between Chart-, Table- and SAQL-Mode. You have to switch from Table to Chart and then choose the right chart Type.